# Local variables and thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java if you have the following method:

```
public int foo(int n) {
    int i=n;
    i = i+1; i = i-1;
    return i;
}
```

So in a sequential program the return value will always be the same as the input.

ie: `j == foo(j)`

However if you have multiple threads call foo, can you guarantee that `j==foo(j)`?

I would say yes that it is guaranteed, because `i` is a local variable, and each thread has its own stack so `i` will be a different memory location for each thread.

I would say you couldn't guarantee that `j==foo(j)` if `i` is a instance variable:

```
private int i;
public int foo(int n) {
    i=n;
    i = i+1; i = i-1;
    return i;
}
```

Because the threads can interleave and the value of `i` can change half way through a thread executing the method, or one thread can increment `i`, but before it gets chance to decrement it, another thread returns with it's input incremented twice and decremented only once.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, but I would add something even more scary: in the case where you're modifying the instance variable, there is absolutely no guarantee that increment and decrement will come in that order for every thread. It is possible for one thread to see an increment followed by a decrement, another seeing them happen in the opposite order.

Comment: @biziclop I can understand multiple incremenents or decrements but seeing just one decrement and one increment happen in that order I don't understand?

Comment: The rule is that `In the absence of a happens before ordering between two operations, the JVM is free to reorder them as it pleases.` Since there's no such relationship between code running in the modifying thread  and code running in the observing thread, it is possible for the observing thread to see the result of the modifications in any order.

Comment: The moral of the story really is: don't make assumptions about the behaviour of the program when concurrent access happens without a well-established order or operations.

Answer (score 7):

> I would say yes that it is guaranteed, because i is a local variable, and each thread has its own stack so i will be a different memory location for each thread.

Exactly. Each call to `foo` will be independent, because `foo` isn't using any shared state.

> I would say you couldn't guarantee that j==foo(j) if i is a instance variable

Correct again. Sounds like you've basically got the right idea. (Note that even "increment" and "decrement" aren't atomic operations, so if you've got multiple threads performing those operations, you end up in tricky situations. That's why `AtomicInteger` exists.)

Comment: ...and even if they are atomic, visibility would still be an issue. That's another reason why `AtomicInteger` exists.

Comment: @biziclop: Yup, absolutely. All kinds of things :)

Comment: Thanks, so a question which says "In the Java code below [the first code in my question], `j==foo(j)` holds for sequential programs. However, if multiple threads call `foo()` then `j==foo(j)` may be false. Explain." doesn't make sense?

Comment: @Jonathan: Yup. Sounds broken to me.